# set PATH to include custom folders

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I refer to [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) to set environment variables.

I'm required to set some variables (GRIFFON_HOME and GROOVY_HOME) for a user and also I want to include `bin` folders to my `PATH` so I edited `~/.pam_environment` as follows.

```
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=letter
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
GRIFFON_HOME=/opt/griffon
GROOVY_HOME=/opt/groovy
PATH=$PATH:$GRIFFON_HOME/bin:$GROOVY_HOME/bin
```

and I executed following command

```
source ~/.pam_environment
```

After this, both `griffon` and `groovy` commands are included in my `PATH` but after I exit that `terminal` and reopen another terminal and try to execute `groovy` or `griffon`, both commands are not included in my `PATH`. But I've found that the variable `GROOVY_HOME` and `GRIFFON_HOME` are still set.

How can I have my `PATH` to include the `bin` folders permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `PATH=$PATH:$GRIFFON_HOME/bin:$GROOVY_HOME/bin` in your `~/.bash_profile` file instead of the `~/.pam_environment` file.

Alternatively you can add the following to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
if [ -f ~/.pam_environment ]; then
   source ~/.pam_environment
fi
```

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist but I have put `PATH=$PATH:$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$GRIFFON_HOME/bin` into my `~/.profile` and is working fine. Is there any difference between setting up in `.bash_profile` and `.profile`? Also `.profile` and `.bash_profile` is set to not recommended in [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) to set environment variables.

Comment: The first shells used a `.profile` file to load the environment for the user, bash will read the `.profile` file if a `.bash_profile` file doesn't exist to maintain backwards compatibility. I do not know the help article recommends not setting environment variables in either the `.profile` or `.bash_profile` files. Unless this is something new for 13.04. On my system the default `.profile` file that is provided to users by Ubuntu has path information in it.